# I accidentally allowed software to load when asked. How do I find out what I allowed (and block it again if needed)?

Tags: macos, mac, permission, mojave

I just upgraded to Mojave, and all went well. When the system restarted, I was shown the name of an application or extension that was being blocked from loading, and I mistakenly authorized it to load. I didn't get a chance to read the name and don't know what it is. How can I figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on precisely what permission it was requesting - though note for future reference you're going to see a lot of these with Mojave, so get into the habit of reading carefully; even to the extent of researching exactly what it is you're allowing before clicking either option. Some apps will never ask again & then you may lose functionality.

Generally, these allowed apps are listed in System Prefs > Security & Privacy > Privacy & then whichever subsection they requested permission for. [I think] The two new options in there since Mojave are Full Disk Access & Automation.
I don't know of any way to determine the date the permission was granted.

[image]

Of course, once identified, there is a simple checkbox to allow/disallow.

Comment: I checked this pane, but didn't see anything resembling the name I thought I saw before allowing access. Also, I have seen lots of times where to authorize access I have to actuall open this pane and allow access—this time, no such thing was offered. It was just two buttons to choose from.